# pyautogui.typewrite, how to have time in between every word

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(2)
f = open("test, 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
```

this scipt types every word in test tab but its does it iimmediately, I want to have time in between every word.

Comment: you could add `time.sleep()` in for loop as well after writing each word

Answer (score 1):

use [`pyautogui.PAUSE`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) to have a pause after each PyAutoGUI call. you can also use `pyautogui.typewrite(word, interval=0.5)` to give delay after writing each character.

Here is an example

```py
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(2)
f = open(r"file.txt", 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.PAUSE=2
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    #pyautogui.typewrite(word, interval=0.25)
    
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your `time.sleep()` inside the for loop.

```
import pyautogui, time
f = open("test, 'r')
for word in f:
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Have a look at this: [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-write-function)

> Eaxmple:

```
pyautogui.write('Hello world!', interval=0.25)
```